Lost Foreign Passport with Canada Visa
I’m studying in Canada on a study permit that’s valid until December 2024 (5 months). Currently, I’m on vacation in Pakistan and have lost my Pakistani passport that contained my still valid TRV (temporary residence visa). I still, however, have my study permit with me. What do I need to do to enter Canada?
As far as I understand, I need to fill out and submit a Verfication of Status (VOS) or Replacement of a Temporary Immigration Document to get a permit to enter Canada, and once Ive entered, I can extend my study permit and then apply for a new TRV.
I contacted my university about this but they told me that I need to apply for a TRV from Pakistan (pakistan’s processing times will apply) and the validity of this TRV will be the same as my study permit (5 months)
Please let me know if anyone’s been in a similar situation, or knows what to do. I would much rather prefer the first option since I need to go back to Canada in the Fall to continue my studies.

Have you contacted the Canadian Embassy in Pakistan? Do you have copies of your lost passport and Visa ?

I’ve been trying to contact them. No luck. Yes I have copies of both
